# I stopped the installation of package abruptly in sdk manager in Linux. Thereafter the window does not open

Tags: linux, android-sdk-manager

I am using Android Studio in Ubuntu 14.4 lts. While installing certain packages through Sdk Manager, i stopped them, as i realized i didn't need them. After which i could not open the sdk manager altogether.

- I tried running it from Android-Studio,
- I tried running it from the terminal by entering the installed android folder then Sdk/tools and executing ./android  as well as ./android sdk
- I tried separately downloading stand-alone sdk tools and tried running it , but that didn't help too

I found such problems already dealt but in Windows, there the path is edited or the java_exe is set.

But i dint find any useful suggestion in case of Linux.
I am finding things really helpless by now. Please help!